# Cannot get JSPF to work

Tags: java, plugins

I'm creating a complex (well for me anyway haha) program in java and require a simple/easy to use plugin framework. I stumbled across JSPF, watched the video and though great! Takes less than 5 minutes to implement.

Reading the doc I have created a plugin interface that extends Plugin from JSPF. made a simple "hello world" method. I then created a test plugin class.

```
package main.plugin.Impl;

import main.plugin.plugin;
import net.xeoh.plugins.base.annotations.PluginImplementation;

/**
 * Created by Adam on 08/05/15.
 */
@PluginImplementation
public class testPlugin implements plugin {
    @Override
    public void helloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The final step was to load the plugin. Here's my main class.

```
package main;


import main.plugin.plugin;
import net.xeoh.plugins.base.PluginManager;
import net.xeoh.plugins.base.impl.PluginManagerFactory;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Adam on 08/05/15.
 */
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PluginManager pm = PluginManagerFactory.createPluginManager();
        pm.addPluginsFrom(new File("src/").toURI());

        plugin p =  pm.getPlugin(plugin.class);
        p.helloWorld();
    }
}
```

According to the examples on the JSPF google code page, that's all I need to do, to be up and running.

However I am getting nullpointerException on the p.helloWorld(); line.

I can clearly see that the plugin isn't getting loaded, but I honestly don't know how to resolve the issue. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT : I've had some success. If I use

```
pm.addPluginsFrom(new URI("classpath://*"));
```

It picks up the plugins and loads them. But if I use the new File method and type the exact path of the class file, it won't load. Any ideas?

EDIT 2 : I figured it out, I had the paths all wrong. All is working fine now.

Comment: did you try to play with the "src/" path? maybe the problem is there. try with full folder name

Comment: Yeah I know thats the issue, I just tried: pm.addPluginsFrom(new URI("classpath://*")); and it loaded the plugin straight away.